# Spinfoams and LQG

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, spin-models, loop-quantum-gravity, adm-formalism

I know up to some degree how spinfoam models and LQG work, but there are some details that i still miss since i have still a naif knowledge.

In the literature it as often said that an open problem is the luck of a proof that those are equivalent theories.

Of course one is concerned with a 3D Hamiltonian description while the other is based on the lagrangian description of a 4D model, but they both, in principle, come from the same starting action and are both quantized via loop quantization.

Where then is the equivalence in principle lacking?

What is happening that separate the two models?